# how to change hash links javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

i have two social media links fb and insta.. how to give separate hash links & how to change text color example fb blue color, insta color yellow  -- JavaScript

```js
let t_p_data = [{ s_media: 'Facebook',},
    {s_media: 'Instagram',},];
let paymentsData = $('.payments-data');
paymentsList = paymentsData.innerHTML;

for (let p_data of t_p_data) {
    paymentsList += `<tr><td><a href="">${p_data.s_media}</a></td></tr>`
} paymentsData.append(paymentsList);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody class="payments-data"></tbody></table>
```

Comment: You need to address your array of objects (t_p_data) to contain the values you need (href and color) then you can use them in your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set hash links and text color inside your loop, then you have to give them in t_p_data:

```
let t_p_data = [{ s_media: 'Facebook', link: 'fb.com', style: {color: '#00f'}},
{s_media: 'Instagram', link: 'insta.com', style: {color: '#ff0'}}];
```

and then add the info in your loop:

```
for (let p_data of t_p_data) {
    paymentsList += `<tr><td><a href=${p_data.link} style=${p_data.style}>${p_data.s_media}</a></td></tr>`
} paymentsData.append(paymentsList);
```